# python - faster way to check the type of item in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has mixed types. I want to check for a certain type and perform calculations. I know I can do something like this:

```
dictionary0 = {'key0':15, 'key1':'string', ...}
for item in dictionary0:
    if isinstance(item, int):
        ##Do something
```

I am curious: is there any faster way to perform something that does not involve a `for` loop?

Comment: Well, for starters, `item` will be the *keys*, and I suspect you meant to loop over the values. But no, there's no significantly faster way that using `isinstance`.

Comment: Probably not if you are searching the dictionary to find the item. If you already know they key then it's much faster.

Comment: Note, generally, containers (with the exception of tuples) having hetergeneous data types is considered code smell.

Comment: The only 'speedup' you can do here is to loop over the `dictionary0.values()` (`dictionary0.itervalues()` on Python 2.x) if you don't care about the keys, but that's as far as you'll get...